# Daikin Remote ARC

Tags: remote-control

I started off attempting to use the  IRRemote    Library and a VS1838B Sensor to capture the Daikin air condition signal.  I’ve read about the timing and in all honesty, I don’t think I can do it on my own so I looked to find the code others had created and adapt it to my own, trying their remote controls first thinking Daikin may only have a few sets.

I can’t confirm that will work as yet because I’ve only been able to find the code below but I’m not quite sure what is the best practice for ripping (stripping out the parts I don’t need) it apart.

When I attempted to capture the IR codes, most of the time I get nothing at all.  My stereo remote is immediate displayed though.

Now the good news,  based on Harizanov’s work, he’s mapped the ARC533 Remote,  which is the same model that I have.

- My Model : FTM18NV2S
- Remote:  ARC533A55
- [Daikin - Smash](http://www.daikin.co.th/en/product/smash/)

NV2S  (On the Inverter)

- Remote:  Doesn’t say anything of use
- [15-Series Wall Mount](http://www.daikinac.com/content/residential/single-zone/15-series/)

Code Here: [Control Daikin air conditioner over the Internet](http://harizanov.com/2012/02/control-daikin-air-conditioner-over-the-internet/)

Code here: [Github: mharizanov/Daikin-AC-remote-control-over-the-Internet](https://github.com/mharizanov/Daikin-AC-remote-control-over-the-Internet)

Can anyone provide a recommendation on how I could trim up this code to try it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can just use the irsend.SendRAW options for this application but I figured since the ARC533 was already mapped out, why not use that.  This is my first attempt at anything like this so I'm a bit out of my realm of understand.

Appreciate any help.

Side note: I have been testing with a stereo remote and have copied the stereo remote On/Off as raw and can send it back, except the timing seems off because it flashes way too slow.

Comment: Anyone at all?    Got no idea how to proceed

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with my daikin A/C. After spending lot of time trying to fix this problem, i found out that is is using long ir codes which is hard to simulate using the IRSenderBitBang (38 kHz). After lot of fustation I used irdevkit.com. It has a ir decoder built in and I can control it using ESP8266. Works well